# Class not recognized in .html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a class (for creating a custom form element) called ListOfDropdowns inside a .html file :

```
class ListOfDropdowns extends HTMLElement {
  
connectedCallback() {
let myParent = document.body
let array = ['Volvo', 'Saab', 'Mercades', 'Audi']
    let template = document.querySelector('#list-of-dropdowns-template').content;
    this.attachShadow({
      mode: 'open'
    }).appendChild(template.cloneNode(true));

    let add_button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#add");
    let remove_button = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#remove");
    let list = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("#list");
    

    add_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
     
  var selectList = document.createElement('select')
  selectList.id = 'mySelect'
  selectList.style.display = 'block'
  myParent.appendChild(selectList)

  //Create and append the options
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var option = document.createElement('option')
    option.value = array[i]
    option.text = array[i]
    selectList.appendChild(option)
  }
  list.appendChild(selectList)
     
    });

    remove_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
     list.lastChild.remove()
    });
  }
}

customElements.define('list-of-dropdowns', ListOfDropdowns);
```

And some lines beneath the class, I have this code:

```
var VIA_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = { TEXT:'text',
                       CHECKBOX:'checkbox',
                       RADIO:'radio',
                       IMAGE:'image',
                       DROPDOWN:'dropdown'
           ListOfDropdowns:'listofdropdowns'
                     };
```

But, I get an error at the line ListOfDropdowns:'listofdropdowns'.

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Both the class ListOfDropdowns and VIA_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE are defined/declared inside the
`<script>` tag inside the `<body>` tag in the .html file.

Comment: You are missing a comma after `DROPDOWN:'dropdown'`

Comment: Thank You so much! That was silly of me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment, I added a comma after `DROPDOWN:'dropdown'` and that resolved the error.

```
var VIA_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE = { TEXT:'text',
                       CHECKBOX:'checkbox',
                       RADIO:'radio',
                       IMAGE:'image',
                       DROPDOWN:'dropdown',
           ListOfDropdowns:'listofdropdowns'
                     };
```